# Gnuplot, wind intensity and direction graph

Tags: gnuplot

I come to you to try to understand how I can fixe my script. I would like to draw on a graph 3 information:

the wind speed, the dust speed, and the direction of the wind.

The way I found for the wind direction is to do it with vector, but maybe there is or are différent way to do it, I am open ^^.

My data are like this

```
#Year   Temp    Wind speed  Origine of the win  Dust        Cos Sin                                     
2019-02-28-09:0 9.7 11  0   21.6    3.141592654 -1  1.22515E-16                                                                                                             
2019-02-28-10:0 10.6    25  45  46.8    3.926990817 -0.707106781    -0.707106781                                                                                                                
2019-02-28-11:0 12.5    18  90  36  4.71238898  -1.83772E-16    -1                                                                                                              
2019-02-28-12:0 13.2    29  260 43.2    7.679448709 0.173648178 0.984807753                                                                                                             
2019-02-28-13:0 13.2    29  90  43.2    4.71238898  -1.83772E-16    -1                                                                                                              
2019-02-28-14:0 13.2    29  90  43.2    4.71238898  -1.83772E-16    -1                                                                                                              
2019-02-28-15:0 13.2    29  260 43.2    7.679448709 0.173648178 0.984807753                                                                                                             
2019-02-28-16:0 13.2    29  90  43.2    4.71238898  -1.83772E-16    -1                                                                                                              
2019-02-28-17:0 13.2    29  45  43.2    3.926990817 -0.707106781    -0.707106781                                                                                                                
2019-02-28-18:0 13.2    29  90  43.2    4.71238898  -1.83772E-16    -1
```

My script is

```
# Setting xdata to time.
#set xdata time
#set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"

# set format x controls the way that gnuplot displays the dates on the x axis.
# "%Y-%m-%d" is the same as "%F", but "%F" applies to output only; it won't work
# for timefmt, which controls data reading.
#set format x "%H:%M"

#set xrange ["2019-02-28-06:00":"2019-02-28-18:00"]
set yrange [0:]

FILE="Donnees.txt"
#unset polar
set angles degrees
#set angles polar
set border 3
set grid mxtics mytics xtics ytics 
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror
set key outside  bmargin left spacing 1.8
set key maxrows 1
set ylabel 'Vitesse [Km/s]'
set xlabel 'Temps [hh:mm]'
#set title "Conditons Meteo" 
set title  font "Arial,14" norotate


#set style arrow 1 head fixed filled size screen 0.03,15,120 ls 1

plot FILE using 0:3 with lines          # just to get the scaling
#SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (2*(GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN))
#SCALE = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / ((GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)) * (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN) * GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE / GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE

LEN=0.001*SCALE
LEN= 2

dx(x) = LEN*x
dy(x) = LEN*x

plot \
    FILE using 0:3:((cos($4))*LEN):((sin($4))*LEN) with vectors fixed filled lc 1 lt 1  title"Origine" ,\
    FILE using 0:3:(dx($7)):(dy($8)) with vectors fixed filled lc 2 lt 2  title"Directions" ,\
    FILE using 0:3 smooth csplines  title "Vitesse",\
    FILE using 0:5 smooth csplines t "Rafale"
```

It works less than more, I mean that if I don't use the time to draw the gaph I don't know how to fixe the same length of the vectors, and when I use the time to draw ... it goes bad the length of the vector are worth and I lose the correct vector direction...

I already looks in many places but I can't figure it out, someone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mis-matched scale on x and y is a problem for the `"with vectors"` plot style.

I do not have a good answer for you using gnuplot 5.2.

In gnuplot 5.3 (the development version) there is a new plot style `"with arrows"` that is  like `"with vectors"` except that the arrow is described by length and angle rather than by dx and dy.

I do not understand the meaning of the values of columns 4 and 6 in your sample data so I may have constructed the wrong lengths, but the following modification of your script shows how to use either a fixed length or a column value for each arrow.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"

# set format x controls the way that gnuplot displays the dates on the x axis.
# "%Y-%m-%d" is the same as "%F", but "%F" applies to output only; it won't work
# for timefmt, which controls data reading.
set format x "%H:%M"

set xrange ["2019-02-28-06:00":"2019-02-28-18:00"]
set yrange [0:]

set border 3
set grid mxtics mytics xtics ytics 
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror
set key bottom center outside spacing 1.8
set key maxrows 1
set ylabel 'Vitesse [Km/s]'
set xlabel 'Temps [hh:mm]'
set title  font "Arial,14" norotate


set style arrow 1 head fixed filled
set ang degree
SCALE = 360.        # length unit equivalent to 10 minutes on x

plot \
    FILE using 1:3:(2.*SCALE):4 with arrows as 1 title "fixed length" ,\
    FILE using 1:5:($6*SCALE):(atan2($7,$8)) with arrows as 1 title "len = column 6" ,\
    FILE using 1:3 smooth csplines  title "Vitesse",\
    FILE using 1:5 smooth csplines t "Rafale"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, and for the tips 'with arows'. 
The colum Origine is the direction where come of the wind in degrees. I need to applyed a correction to have the direction.

And sorry for the 'dust' it is Gust.... Mistake.
It is great, yours arrows are great.
It is really nice I will use the 5.3 version. Tomorrow I will try to find a way to have a scale which will give same size of arrows even if I reduce or enlarge the number of hours showed. To have the same arrows wich a graph of 5 hours as a graph with 12 hours.
Let me try and come with a solution or not.

Thanks

Comment: One question, where can i find a compiled version of the 5.3 version beta or do I need to compile the source?

Comment: It work perfectly with SCALE = 1.*((GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN)/(GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN))
Thanks